# Xcode Core-Data to-many relationship: addObject method error

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have the following core-data structure:
[image: core data]

I am trying to add Vocabulary objects to the Group class.

My attempts at doing this with the [Group addObject: VocabularyObject] method have 
come to no avail.

```
 AppDelegate *delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc]init];

 Group *group = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //I have an array with 'Group' objects

    //create vocabulary item
    Vocabulary *vocabularyEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Vocabulary" inManagedObjectContext:[delegate managedObjectContext]];
    vocabularyEntity.prompt = @"Here is a cool prompt";
    vocabularyEntity.definition = @"Here is an even cooler definition";

    [delegate saveContext];

    [group addTermsObject:vocabularyEntity];
```

I am getting this error, I used exception breakpoints and the error comes from the addTermsObject call.

```
[__NSDictionaryI addTermsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74c4f70
```

The object I am trying to add is definitely a Vocabulary object, so i'm not exactly sure what the problem could be.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states that your

```
Group *group = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

is *not* a managed object as you expected, but an `NSDictionary`. Perhaps you fetched the array using

```
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

in the fetch request? In that case all the fetched objects are just dictionaries without
any connection to the managed object context, and you can't use these dictionaries to
establish any relationships.

**UPDATE:** Another error is here:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc]init];
```

This allocates a *new* application delegate instead of using the existing one. This is
probably not what you want and you should replace it with

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. I am getting data from the AppDelegate so I wrote a method to return an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries that store data so that I could quickly put it into my tableview. I added another function that just returns the fetched array, no more errors.

Comment: i'm now getting another error unfortunately, Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x8197b60 <x-coredata://1F273438-3607-46B4-9018-1340792AF990/Group/p1>''

Comment: @Yoni201: "CoreData could not fulfill a fault" can have multiple reasons, that is really difficult to say. It could be that the managed object context that was used to create the objects does not exist anymore. - I also just noticed that you create a new AppDelegate each time in your code. Does that mean that you create a new context each time? The Group and the Vocabulary objects must live in the same context to create a relationship.

Comment: Should I always be using the context from AppDelegate? I'm not entirely sure how I should be doing things.

Comment: @Yoni201: There is not a simple yes/no answer to that. Using a single context in the app is one option. You would create additional contexts if you a) want to perform operations on a background thread, or b) if you need a temporary context for editing that you can discard if necessary. (There may be more reasons.) - So if you are not sure than I would recommend to use a single context.

Comment: How should I go about solving the "could not fulfill a fault" issue? I moved my core-data methods from AppDelegate to a singleton, and I instantiate the singleton, and my methods take a context as an argument, that way I always use the same one. I'm not sure where this problem is coming from. Would it be possible for me to show you my code? (Although i'm sure you're busy...)

Comment: @Yoni201: I do not have general advice how to solve that. Perhaps start reading https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html or some of the many Google hits for "Core Data could not fulfill a fault". - At present I do not have time. If you provide some download link to your project I might look at it later.

Comment: I used the existingObjectWithId method to check if the object was actually being created, it was, same error with this code:
    if([managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:[vocabWord objectID] error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"vocab word exists");
        [group addTermsObject:vocabWord];
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31994/discussion-between-yoni201-and-martin-r)

Comment: Yes, please! I would really appreciate it.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wllgi1j4ohqe5rz/B5sSLyleht
Thank you.